# How to mod_rewrite based on http-header content-type

Tags: json, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, content-type

is it possible to redirect the user, based on the HTTP-Header `content-type`?

For example:

1)

An Application is trying to load `localhost/res/123/var/abc` and the `content-type` is set to:

```
application/json
```

The server should just return the JSON-Result to the application (which is implemented).

2)

If a normal web-browser is visiting the url `localhost/res/123/var/abc`, the `content-type` is set to:

```
text/html
```

In this case the server should redirect the browser to output a webview (e.g. `index_web.html`).

Can i realize something like this without using PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The content type is not set at request time, so far as I am aware. Thus, you would need to check if the browser is sending an `Accept` header, which describes to the server what kinds of data it will accept (and display) without downloading it. Most browsers do this. They send the following header string to the server (this is obtained from Chrome):

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

Therefore, you would need to check the `Accept` header using a condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} text/html [NC]
# Then, add your RewriteRules here ...
```

This will check to see if `text/html` is contained in the `Accept` header.

Comment: The problem with this is that quite often (and quite correctly) the `Accept` header will contain both desired content types, but with different `q` weightings.  Your test doesn't check the relative weightings of the test, nor does it handle wildcards. You can perhaps do what you want with `mod_negotiation`, though it's not very powerful.  Otherwise you're left having to do it yourself in a script.